# multiple check boxes in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have   problem when  i  go to the  edit link  from the admin page  on the update page  check boxes are not update shown .please guide me.
Here is my view

```
<?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'partecipants', array('Members'=>'Members','sites'=>'sites','packages'=>'packages',' Report'=>'Report'),array('class'=>'tst')); ?>
```

here is  my controller

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{

    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Admin_user_groups']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Admin_user_groups'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->group_id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: In which format checkbox data saved in DB? Different related table?

Comment: In  data base comma seperated  values are store.forexample 'Members','sites','packages' in permission column of the table

Answer (score 1):

while updating you should pass the participants as an array to the view i.e.

$model->participants = array(1,2,3,4) // this array contains the participants id.

For more checkout this link

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/41616-checkboxlist-checked-on-update-time/

Answer (score 0):

If you saving checkboxes with coma in DB field then you need to make string from your array with [implode](http://php.net/implode):

```
if(isset($_POST['Admin_user_groups']))
{
    $model->attributes=implode(',',$_POST['Admin_user_groups']);
    if($model->save())
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->group_id));
}
```